# Testing DialogFragments with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-dialogfragment

I have a couple of questions about testing `DialogFragment` classes with Robolectric, as I've encountered a total lack of information on this topic in Internet.

1. What are the right arguments to pass to `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)`?
2. I have trouble passing arguments to `DialogFragment`, I'm using the following approach:

   ```
   activity = new Activity();
   dialog = new DialogFragment();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   dialog.setArguments(bundle);
   FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
   ft.add(dialog, "fragment");
   ft.commit();
   ```

Whenever the code tries to access arguments it crashes with a `NullPointerException`.

Will highly appreciate any ideas on these topics.

Comment: Could you include code for your DialogFragment class? Is there a reason you are not using DialogFragment#show()? The documentation shows how you should extend DialogFragment to create your own custom dialog: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: @Egor, have you resolved this?

Answer (score -1):

You are using the `DialogFragment` wrong. You should not commit the fragment, but call `show` on the `DialogFragment`.

```
activity = new Activity();
dialog = new DialogFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
dialog.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
dialog.show(ft, "fragment");
```

Comment: show() does nearly the same thing - adds the DialogFragment to the transaction and commits it.